# Rolling sum on sequentially linked data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on large a legacy dataset with sequentially related data of which I lack the words to explain so I made a beautiful paint image. This isn't of course of the real dataset but it is close. In the example there are three sequences.

[image: record representation of dataset]

Each record has an ID and a value. It also has a pointer to the next related ID. The sequence length is random and stops when the next related ID hits a 0 value. All records are only used once in one sequence, meaning they cant merge or split. A sequence can consist of only one record.

What I need to accomplish is to get the rolling sum on each record of a sequence using a SQL query(SQL server 2014). I know how to do this if there is a common identifier in the sequence, but in this case there is not.

I have been able to accomplish it in Excel (for what it's worth) by finding the previous sum (if it exists) and adding the current value. But I'm unable to translate it to SQL. Does anyone know where to start to get to the end goal of the 'rolling sum result' column in SQL?

[image: example of sequence data in Excel]

```
[previous sum] formule: =IFNA(INDEX([rolling sum formula],MATCH([@id],[next_pointer],0),0),0)
[rolling sum result] formula: =[@[previous sum]]+[@value]

*The data sequences aren't sorted like in the Excel example. This just makes it easier to read in the example.
```

Comment: Are there any merges of sequences, in other words can two rows with the same pointer?

Comment: @Charlieface That's an important detail. they can't merge. I've included this in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like a RECURSIVE query.

You can do this with CTE. This is a test with your data (the column you seek is "cumul", the others are there to help understand what's going on):

```
WITH sequenza AS (
    SELECT       
        id, 
        value,
        nextid,
        id AS lastid,
        value as cumul
    FROM       
        items
    WHERE nextid = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        curr.id, 
        curr.value,
        curr.nextid,
        prev.lastid,
        prev.cumul + curr.value AS cumul
    FROM 
        items AS curr
        INNER JOIN sequenza AS prev
            ON prev.id = curr.nextid
)
SELECT * FROM sequenza
WHERE id = 31;
```

To do this in reverse order... there is probably more than one way. Off the top of my head I'd get, for each chain (identified by its lastid), the minimum and maximum cumul value, then I'd apply the ladder algorithm - in this case the descending rolling sum is VALMIN+VALMAX-ROLLING.

So, something like

```
WITH sequenza AS (
    SELECT       
        id, 
        value,
        nextid,
        id AS lastid,
        value as cumul
    FROM       
        items
    WHERE nextid = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        curr.id, 
        curr.value,
        curr.nextid,
        prev.lastid,
        prev.cumul + curr.value AS cumul
    FROM 
        items AS curr
        INNER JOIN sequenza AS prev
            ON prev.id = curr.nextid
),
sequenza2 AS (
    SELECT       
        id, 
        value,
        nextid,
        id AS lastid,
        value as cumul
    FROM       
        items
    WHERE nextid = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        curr.id, 
        curr.value,
        curr.nextid,
        prev.lastid,
        prev.cumul + curr.value AS cumul
    FROM 
        items AS curr
        INNER JOIN sequenza2 AS prev
            ON prev.id = curr.nextid
)
SELECT sequenza.*, m1+m2-cumul AS cumulasc FROM sequenza
JOIN (
  SELECT lastid, MIN(cumul) AS m1, MAX(cumul) AS m2
  FROM sequenza2
  GROUP BY lastid
) AS cirpo ON (sequenza.lastid = cirpo.lastid)
ORDER BY sequenza.lastid, cumul DESC
```

Comment: This is looking very promising! But when i execute the query the sequence seems flipped (counts from last in sequence to first) is there a way to turn this around?

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was almost what i needed. I noticed it was taking the last item in the sequence as first sum (for example: at id 31 the cumulasc result was 82 which is the last value from the sequence,  the next id would correctly add 29 which is the value from id 31). To make it exactly as the Excel example I removed m1 from the join and formula and added the current value like this: "SELECT sequenza.*, m2-cumul+value AS cumulasc FROM sequenza". This works perfectly now. Thanks again!